# Save Stream with different encoding as a UTF8 file

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a Stream in which there is **uploaded text file**. The file can have any encoding - ANSI, UTF8 without BOM, UTF8 with BOM. The file has characters which are **specific for some languages** - e.g. ąę. **I need to save all files as UTF8 BOM files on the server side**, but I can't force all users to upload me UTF8 BOM files. Special characters in saved file must maintain correct - so ąę. How can I do this?

I have:

```
        using (Stream inputStream = file.InputStream)
        {
            byte[] bytes = ReadFully2(inputStream);
            string utf8string = .....what here?.....
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("", utf8string, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        }


public static byte[] ReadFully2(Stream input)
{
    input.Position = 0;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        input.CopyTo(ms);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, guessing the codePage of a file without other informations can bequite tricky even for an expert. Programming it in automatic is, IMO, impossible in a way that is acceptably robust.

Comment: The problem is reading the text using the correct encoding. If by ANSI you mean the well-defined ANSI codepage, you could read everything with UTF8Encoding - UTF8 and ANSI are the same for the ANSI character range. If by ANSI you mean "any local codepage" you have a problem.

Comment: You can force the users to specify a codepage, or you can try to read the file using different codepages and check for the Unicode Replacement character (�) in invalid encodings. Unfortunately, *some* encodings will result in garbled text instead of �. Forcing the users to specify the encoding is safer